# How is space divided amongst flex items when flex-basis and flex-grow both are set?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am going through a basic flexbox [tutorial from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and cant get my head around on how is the remaining space divided amongst the flex item, when `flex-basis` is set.

In the [live demo](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/css/css-layout/flexbox/flexbox1.html), I set the following code:

```
article {
  flex: 1 200px;
}

article:nth-of-type(3) {
  flex: 2 200px;
}
```

My browser screen is `1369px`, after taking the scrollbar out I am left with `1349px`. MDN says that

> "Each flex item will first be given `200px` of the available space. After that, the rest of the available space will be shared out according to the proportion units."

So the available space after min `200px` is given to each article should be `1349px - 3*200px = 749px`. Now, the article three should get half of the available space plus `200px`, that is `200 + 749/2 = 575.5`. Taking `10px` margin space out from both sides we get `555.5px`, but in my laptop it occupies `535.5px`.

Below is the working demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      header {
        background: purple;
        height: 100px;
      }

      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin: 0;
      }

      article {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        background: aqua;
        flex: 1 200px;
      }

      /* Add your flexbox CSS below here */

      section {
        display: flex;
      }
      article:nth-of-type(3) {
        flex: 2 200px;
      }
```

```html
<header>
      <h1>Sample flexbox example</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
      <article>
        <h2>First article</h2>

        <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Second article</h2>

        <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Third article</h2>

        <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub hammock.</p>

        <p>Cray food truck brunch, XOXO +1 keffiyeh pickled chambray waistcoat ennui. Organic small batch paleo 8-bit. Intelligentsia umami wayfarers pickled, asymmetrical kombucha letterpress kitsch leggings cold-pressed squid chartreuse put a bird on it. Listicle pickled man bun cornhole heirloom art party.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
```

1. Please explain how is space divided amongst flex items when flex-basis and flex-grow both are set?
2. If I do `article:nth-of-type(3) { flex: 2; }` it doesn't give double space to article 3, why?

Comment: did you consider padding in your code? it makes a lot of difference. Share your full code inside the question so we can see all the padding/margin/border and also box-sizing

Comment: @TemaniAfif  I've added a working demo where I changed box-sizing to border-box, but still the 3rd article  is 545px not 555px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin should be considered initially and removed from the total width in order to calculate the free space. Not later, like you are doing.

So all your elements start with `200px` width and `20px` margin. The free sapce will be `1350px - 3*200px - 3*20x = 690px`. Now, the article three should have a width equal to `2/4*690px + 200px = 545px` (and not `555px`)

without `box-sizing` you will have `1350px - 3*220px - 3*20x = 630px` and the width will be `535px`